# How to get all properties from filter expression OData

Tags: c#, expression, odata

I have OData filter query and I want to get filter properties. Here is my query:

```
Product?$filter=Name eq 'Apple'
```

I'm getting its `Name` property like this:

```
var propertyName=((filterQuery?.FilterClause?.Expression as BinaryOperatorNode)?.Left as SingleValuePropertyAccessNode)?.Property?.Name;
```

Now I'm creating another query which has two properties:

```
 Product?$filter=Name eq 'Apple' and Price eq 120
```

How can I get `Name` and `Price`? Is there any simple way to get properties from filter expression?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves your problem, but just in case you are looking for all available entity attributes in Dynamics 365, there are documentation pages, where all attributes are listed:

Here is an example of PhoneCall entity attributes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/phonecall?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9

In the side menu, there are all other possible entities.